# What is the meaning of this code in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am newbie to Javascript, I have difficulties getting the meaning of this code properly. I would like to share my thought over the code,and I need your guidance to understand it correctly.

```
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me!" id="say_hi" />
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js_event_01.js"></script>
</body>

function hi_and_bye() {
  window.alert('Hi!');
  window.alert('Bye!');
 }
var hi_button = document.getElementById("say_hi");
hi_button.onclick = hi_and_bye;
```

My understanding: the event "onclick" calls the function "hi_and_bye" when ID is "get_alerts". Similarly this could be applied to any event, and I can give an id attribute to any element and that id would be responsible to make an accessible corresponding input element.

Comment: whats in 'js_event_01.js' file??

Comment: Although it seems that, the file isn't affecting anything in your code.

Comment: No, it does make its affect. When I click on button it shows three alerts. What makes you think that it is not doing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. You could give an `id` to any DOM element, not only inputs. Then using the `getElementById` you could retrieve a reference to this element.

In this example that's what you are doing:

```
// Get a reference to a DOM element that has id="say_hi"
var hi_button = document.getElementById("say_hi");

// subscribe to the onclick event handler of the DOM element we retrieved on  
// the previous line and attach this handler to the hi_and_bye javascript function
hi_button.onclick = hi_and_bye;
```

I don't think that the body of the function itself requires any more explanation: it will just display 2 alerts once after the other when this function executes.

Comment: What I see in document.getElementById("say_hi") by printing is a reference,and you have assigned that reference to variable that calls onclick event. Where I am getting confused is the relation ship between event handler and input type. Do we always make the relation ship between event handler and input like this?

Comment: No, not always. But that's the correct way because you have separated javascript from markup. You could have also assigned the `onclick` event handler inside the markup: `<input type="button" value="Click Me!" id="say_hi" onclick="hi_and_bye();" />`. Now you no longer need the 2 lines of javascript code. But I wouldn't recommend you using inline assignment of the handler like this.

Comment: Yes I see that way in the book. I need to clarify the only thing that event apply on input element ,and are accesible via above two methods.

Comment: Yes, the event handler will apply to the input element's `onclick` event.

Comment: Okay, I have got it . And so far I have cleared my concepts. Thanks very much for your answer and response. Good luck.